# App crashes when press swiped delete button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My app goes to top_level_code file and says `Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` when I use UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete

I want when the user swipes to left on a uitableview row it shows delete button and when he pressed it the row should be deleted.
it works correctly some times, but many times it will crash however when I run the app again the row is deleted. Here is my code :

```
var doItList = [String]()

var stared = false

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var staredBtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var addDoItField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var doItTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("doItList") != nil {

        doItList = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("doItList") as [String]

    }

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return doItList.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = doItList[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        doItList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(doItList, forKey: "doItList")

        doItTableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```

Comment: Can u pls post your full crash report

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334706/swift-array-removeatindex-error. It looks like your doItList is an NSArray not NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the error

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
(lldb)

Comment: this is not error log...this is just auto layout constrain warning.